# Count number of entity objects with specific value? Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following;

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0 //HERE
    }
```

I am trying to access the objects which are CORE DATA ENTITIES (which also have a many to one relationship with another entity) and count the objects (if any) that have essentially the relationship entitie's "meal.name == (meal!.name!)"

Is this possible?

Thanks

The following code signifies that I am grabbing all the FoodConsumed entities regardless of the meal that they are in.

I want to use the above method to determine how many entities are linked to another with the specific other entity property (meal.name == CURRENT MEAL)

Thanks

```
frc = m.ds_frcForEntityNamed("FoodConsumed", withPredicateFormat: nil, predicateObject: nil, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "descr", ascending: true)], andSectionNameKeyPath: nil)

        // This controller will be the frc delegate
        frc.delegate = self;

        // Perform fetch, and if there's an error, log it
        do {
            try frc.performFetch()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Comment: Maybe but do you really want to do that in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: Ya because I need to know if there are any objects with the same meal name and to give the number of those objects back

Comment: Ok but that is not the purpose of that method. Anyway you need to provide more code for this, primarily the class you have in the array.

Comment: I updated the code